# How to convert ragged tensor to list of tensors inside a graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a ragged tensor with variable shape in the 2nd dimension N x ? x 4, I'd like to convert it to a list of tensors.

Down below is a function that works, but only when it's not decorated with tf.function. I need this function to run inside a tf graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf

raggedTensor = tf.ragged.constant([[[0.7688891291618347, 0.3979208469390869, 0.9807137250900269, 0.5825483798980713], 
                                    [0.69159334897995, 0.48753976821899414, 0.7804230451583862, 0.5539296865463257]], 
                                   
                                   [[0.5818965435028076, 0.343869686126709, 0.8541288375854492, 0.6288187503814697], 
                                    [0.636405348777771, 0.6720571517944336, 0.7466434240341187, 0.7985518574714661]], 
                                   
                                   [[0.65436190366745, 0.47322067618370056, 0.9061073660850525, 0.6343377828598022]], 
                                   
                                   [[0.7395644187927246, 0.6922436356544495, 0.9913792610168457, 1.0], 
                                    [0.7860392928123474, 0.44102346897125244, 0.8941574096679688, 0.637432873249054]]])


def convertGT(x):
    out = []
    for i in range(x.nrows()):
        out.append(x[i].to_tensor())
        
    return out

#runs fine
convertGT(raggedTensor)

[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[0.7688891 , 0.39792085, 0.9807137 , 0.5825484 ],
        [0.69159335, 0.48753977, 0.78042305, 0.5539297 ]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[0.58189654, 0.3438697 , 0.85412884, 0.62881875],
        [0.63640535, 0.67205715, 0.7466434 , 0.79855186]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.6543619 , 0.47322068, 0.90610737, 0.6343378 ]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[0.7395644 , 0.69224364, 0.99137926, 1.        ],
        [0.7860393 , 0.44102347, 0.8941574 , 0.6374329 ]], dtype=float32)>]


@tf.function
def convertGT(x):
    out = []
    for i in range(x.nrows()):
        out.append(x[i].to_tensor())
        
    return out

#this will throw the error
convertGT(raggedTensor)

InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("while/RaggedToTensor/RaggedTensorToTensor:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=while_body_4893, id=140025401503696); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=convertGT, id=140025402568040).
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to work with lists within tf.function: python side effects (like appending to lists) only happen the first time you call a Function with a set of inputs. Afterwards, the traced tf.Graph is reexecuted, without executing the Python code.

See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#python_side_effects

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution, here it is:

```
@tf.function
def unstackRaggedBBox(ragged):
    #convert the ragged to a zero padded tensor
    _tensor = ragged.to_tensor()
    
    ret = []
    for i in range(_tensor.shape[0]):
        #create a mask/remove the 0 values
        mask = tf.cast(_tensor[i], dtype=tf.bool)              
        row = tf.boolean_mask(_tensor[i], mask, axis=0)

        #reshape the tensor to Nx4
        size = tf.cast(tf.shape(row, out_type=tf.dtypes.int32) / 4, tf.int32)
        row = tf.reshape(row, [size[0], 4])        
        ret.append(row)
        
    return ret
```

I think the ragged_tensor slice operation caused the problem, lists are working fine in graphs.